# Possible to force 'Next/Previous Done' bar in iOS to not show?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I'd like to not show the Next/Previous 'tab'-bar sitting above the keyboard when a text area or input field are active on a webpage. Any ideas?

Comment: please describe more.

Comment: Do you want to do this for your application or in browser or in UIWebView? Whatever it is, you have control over your application only.

Comment: Do you mean the navigation bar at the top of the screen?

Comment: No, the form navigation bar essentially.